# Unable to download txt file

Tags: php

I am trying to download a text file from same location, but it is writing all text from the txt file to my web page. 
Tried many other codes from online but problem remains same.

```
    $file =  'Key_'.date('m-d-Y_G_i_s').'.txt';
    $fp = fopen($file, "a+");

        $write = fputs($fp,$txt."\r\n");
    for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
        {
            $key=GenarateKey();

            $t=$t.$key;
    $t=$t.'<br/>';
            $p=$p.$_POST['period'];
    $p=$p.'<br/>';

    $txt=($i+1);
            $txt=$txt."                    ".$key."                    ".$_POST['period']."                 ".$_POST['affiliation_no'];

    $write = fputs($fp,$txt."\r\n");
    }


        if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
}
```

[Here is my output image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gDrR.png)
Please help me out from this. 
Thank You.

Comment: Your code have syntax errors. I think your script throw errors, so not completely work.

Comment: Is it specific to a particular browser? I remember having some problems (couple of years back) with IE when I was trying to force download of a PDF file.

Comment: No, having same issue on all browsers. @VivekAthalye

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are having mismatched braces, check the following code,

```
$file =  'Key_'.date('m-d-Y_G_i_s').'.txt';
$fp = fopen($file, "a+");

    $write = fputs($fp,$txt."\r\n");
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++)
    {
        $key=GenarateKey();

        $t=$t.$key;
$t=$t.'<br/>';
        $p=$p.$_POST['period'];
$p=$p.'<br/>';

$txt=($i+1);
        $txt=$txt."                    ".$key."                    ".$_POST['period']."                 ".$_POST['affiliation_no'];

$write = fputs($fp,$txt."\r\n");
}


    if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}//Add this close brace
```

Comment: Thank you, but I just forget to put the closing braces here.